# How to update a ComboBox's textbox with different text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, user-interface

I've got an editable ComboBox. When the user selects an item, I would like to overrid the text  within the textbox to be a different value than what has been selected. For example, no matter what the user's selection, I would like the following to display in the textbox of the editable Combobox: "[Selected Table]". This is what I tried so far:

```
private void cmbValue1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBoxItem selection = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;

            //If the tag is a TableContainer, then the user has selected a sub-query.
            if (selection != null && selection.Tag != null && selection.Tag.GetType() == typeof(TableContainer))
            {
                (sender as ComboBox).Text = "[Selected Table]";
            }
        }
```

The user's actual selected value is being displayed instead, so I figure that once the compiler finishes my method implementation, it is going elsewhere and changes the text to that of the selected item.

Comment: Have you tried modifying `SelectedText` rather than `Text` ?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal - Doesn't seem to have selectedText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override `ItemTemplate` and `ItemContainerStyle`, this way the Items in the dropdown will show correctly but the Item in the ComboBox will be `"[Selected Table]"`

Example:

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- The template for the SelectedItem -->
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="[Selected Table]" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <!-- The style for the dropdown items -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                     <!-- Add dataTemplate here if you are binding to complex object -->
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Working copy:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="132" Width="278" Name="UI">

    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="[Selected Table]" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items.Add("Item1");
        Items.Add("Item2");
        Items.Add("Item3");
        Items.Add("Item4");
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; }
    }
}
```

Result:

DropDown: [image] Selected: [image]

---

### Edit:

Maybe this?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication17.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication17"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="500" Name="UI">
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <ComboBox x:Name="combo" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding}" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, ElementName=combo}" Value="false">
                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding MyText, ElementName=UI}" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _myText;
    private ObservableCollection<string> _items = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items.Add("Item1");
        Items.Add("Item2");
        Items.Add("Item3");
        Items.Add("Item4");
        MyText = "StackOverflow";
    }

    public string MyText
    {
        get { return _myText; }
        set { _myText = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyText"); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(e));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is it however possible to do this without changing the control template?

Comment: hmmmm... I added another way that does not override the `ComboBox` `ControlTemplate`, bit it still overrrides the `ItemTemplate`, Give it a try, I'm sure we can find a nice way to do this.

Comment: The main issue however is that I do not want the text to always be [Selected Table], but would like to change this dynamically. Is it possible using this method?

Comment: I'll try adapting your solution to my problem and see what I can manage. Thanks!

Comment: yes, with this new method you can bind the value in the trigger to whatever value you want, I updated answer to show

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do what was asked in the question is to remove the event and then add it back afterwards. There is no way to prevent the firing of the event though without overriding the class and building this functionality yourself or using an alternative method.

```
    private void cmbValue1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBoxItem selection = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;

        //If the tag is a TableContainer, then the user has selected a sub-query.
        if (selection != null && selection.Tag != null && selection.Tag.GetType() == typeof(TableContainer))
        { 
            //This is the only way to disable an event action
            (sender as ComboBox).TextChanged -= sender_OnTextChanged; 
            (sender as ComboBox).Text = "[Selected Table]";
            (sender as ComboBox).TextChanged += sender_OnTextChanged; 

            //But as said above though, you could also do this:
            (sender as ComboBox).SelectedText = "[Selected Table]";
        }
    }
```

Comment: TextChanged is not available in the ComboBox

Comment: SelectedValueChanged** Sorry